# GET command is giving two kinds of ouput,why?

Tags: php, shell, get

iam using GET command to get the content of a page.When i write the same command on shell prompt it gives correct result but when i use that in PHP file then sometimes its giving correct result but sometimes it gives only half of the content i.e. end-half portion only.

Iam using following command in shell script :-

```
GET http://www.abc.com/ -H "Referer:http://www.abcd.com/"
```

and following in PHP file :-

```
$data=exec('GET http://www.abc.com/ -H "Referer:http://www.abcd.com/"');
echo $data;
```

Now please tell why this command is not giving full content of the page when im using it in php file.

Comment: Why on earth are you shelling out to LWP instead of using curl or fopen? i.e. things with PHP APIs.

Comment: In fairness, when I want to hack together code really quickly I do this. Although, that's for the kind of code I use once then delete. If you don't plan to do this (@original poster) I suggest you look at cURL and fsockopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec` only returns the last line from the command output. To return the full output, pass in a second argument by reference:

`exec('GET http://www.abc.com/ -H "Referer:http://www.abcd.com/"', &$data);`

`$data` will be an array with one element per line of output

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier:

```
$data = `GET http://www.abc.com/ -H "Referer:http://www.abcd.com/"`;
echo $data;
```

Assuming shell_exec function (that's what the backtick ` really is) isn't disabled.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative with pure php:

```
$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Referer: http://www.abc.com/\r\n"
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.abc.com/', false, $context);
```